# Insert NULL value in db using Raw sql queries in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am using raw sql queries in my rails application. I want to insert NULL value in one my rows, like how active record does using nil so that i will get that row when i do `Table.find_by_column(nil)`. I tried '#{nil}' its entering as nothing db column is blank like this ' ' i want it to be NULL.

Comment: what query you are using, show the complete query how you are trying to do it

Comment: "INSERT into table_name (`r_id`, `r_name`) VALUES (0,'#{nil}')"

Comment: try this `"INSERT into table_name (r_id, r_name) VALUES (0,null)"`

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this.

```
sql = "INSERT into table_name (r_id, r_name) VALUES (1, null)"

records_array = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `nil` instead of `#{nil}`

```
Table.column = nil
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Model.find_by_sql "SELECT * FROM table  where column is NULL"
```

Comment: Thank u @SachinR but i want it like like that while inserting it should be raw sql but while searching it will be ActivRecord.

Answer (score 0):

```
Model.find_by_column(nil)
```

This will give record which column's value is nil

Answer (score 0):

You can update all records using:

```
Model.update_all(:field_name => nil)
```

Then you can find all records that are nil using:

```
Model.where(:field_name => nil)
```